# 2016 tucson. Is my steering wheel incorrectly installed?

Tags: hyundai, steering, tucson, suv

I had a bushing issue. After getting that fixed my skid light is on and my reverse camera has become crooked (the steering wheel square is sideways while the steering is straight). Also while at low speeds my steering wheel automatically changes direction to the right. I have it to a mechanic to calibrate it but he wasn't able. What could be the issue? And remedy?

Comment: There may be more damage to fix than just the bush, what was the cause - hitting a kerb?

Comment: No. Just some bad noise. The steering was fine before, while I had that Bush issue. After the fix it seems that the steering is incorrectly set, pulls to the right to correct it

Comment: Is pulling a lot to the right or just a little? Have you checked the tire pressures, tires etc? Which bush was it? A suspension bush or one in the steering column?

Comment: It's motor based so I'd assume its correcting itself to the right. Tire pressure is the first thing I checked. Suspension Bush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not your steering wheel: the front wheels of your car are misaligned. Probably the mechanic that worked on your cars suspension didn't mark any settings before he started taking it apart to replace the bushes, so part of the suspension reassembly was guesswork. In my opinion an alignment job should be standard practice after most suspension work.

I'd recommend to have an aligment done soon, it shouldn't be that expensive and the tires of your car will wear out quickly when driving around like this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see how the alignment goes and get back.

Comment: Also, remember that new suspension bushes should be finally tightened once the weight is back on the wheels...

Comment: apparently the tyres were different.